# Function is not working as standalone with $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a page with autoscroll using jquery animate. It is very simple- it loads a xml data to single DIV, then sets body size with this size+some amount of pixels. I want it to autoscroll to bottom. If I use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var z=document.getElementById('main_container').clientHeight+2400;
speed=z*3

$('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: z,
    easing: "linear"}, speed); 
});
```

It is working. But since I would like to use this function more than once, I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(pagescroll());

        function pagescroll(){
        var z=document.getElementById('main_container').clientHeight+2400;
        speed=z*3

        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: z,
            easing: "linear"}, speed); 
        });
```

and I'm done. It won't work. I tried putting it in different parts of website (head, body, changing order of $document.ready and function itself) but it won't help. I also tried to run this function by adding onload to body element. Why I can't use that get this thing to vork.

Comment: `$(document).ready(pagescroll)` or just `$(pagescroll)` will do it.

Comment: @user2584809 I've edited answer. Please try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also an error with the notation of the animate function. You have to write it so:

```
$(document).ready(pagescroll);

    function pagescroll(){
        var z=document.getElementById('main_container').clientHeight + 2400,
            speed = z * 3;

        // this is one way to write animate():
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: z}, speed, "linear");

        // this is another way to write animate(), choose one of it
        $('body,html').animate(
            {scrollTop: z},
            { easing: "linear", duration: speed}
        );
    };
```

[See here how to use animate correctly](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `pagescroll()`, but `pagescroll` only. It should work.

```
$(document).ready(pagescroll);

        function pagescroll(){
        var z=document.getElementById('main_container').clientHeight+2400;
        speed=z*3

        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: z,
            easing: "linear"}, speed); 
        });
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work either.

Comment: There's an error with the animate-notation: property and easing in same object.

Answer (score 0):

if you put parentheses after a function name, it calls it immediately, instead of passing the function as an argument. It should be:

```
$(document).ready(pagescroll);
```